# How to resolve conflict between same classes coming from 2 different jar?

Tags: java, spring, maven, jar, dependencies

I am in process of updating my project's jdk from 8 to 11 . So, while running I am facing such kind of warnings

```html
org.aspectj.internal.lang.annotation.ajcDeclareAnnotation scanned from multiple locations: jar:file:///Users/nishtha.garg/.m2/repository/org/aspectj/aspectjrt/1.9.2/aspectjrt-1.9.2.jar!/org/aspectj/internal/lang/annotation/ajcDeclareAnnotation.class, jar:file:///Users/nishtha.garg/.m2/repository/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/1.9.2/aspectjweaver-1.9.2.jar!/org/aspectj/internal/lang/annotation/ajcDeclareAnnotation.class

javax.mail.search.MessageIDTerm scanned from multiple locations: jar:file:///Users/nishtha.garg/.m2/repository/javax/mail/mail/1.4/mail-1.4.jar!/javax/mail/search/MessageIDTerm.class, jar:file:///Users/nishtha.garg/.m2/repository/javax/mail/javax.mail-api/1.6.2/javax.mail-api-1.6.2.jar!/javax/mail/search/MessageIDTerm.class

org.aspectj.lang.reflect.DeclarePrecedence scanned from multiple locations: jar:file:///private/var/folders/rw/9_fr4s6s01d5vcykl3fqkd7d3j59v0/T/jetty-0.0.0.0-0-attache-api-rest.war-_api-any-13258162480745251787.dir/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/aspectjrt-1.9.2.jar!/org/aspectj/lang/reflect/DeclarePrecedence.class, jar:file:///private/var/folders/rw/9_fr4s6s01d5vcykl3fqkd7d3j59v0/T/jetty-0.0.0.0-0-attache-api-rest.war-_api-any-13258162480745251787.dir/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/aspectjweaver-1.9.2.jar!/org/aspectj/lang/reflect/DeclarePrecedence.class

org.apache.cxf.transport.http.policy.HTTPClientAssertionBuilder$HTTPClientPolicyAssertion scanned from multiple locations: jar:file:///private/var/folders/rw/9_fr4s6s01d5vcykl3fqkd7d3j59v0/T/jetty-0.0.0.0-0-attache-api-rest.war-_api-any-13258162480745251787.dir/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/cxf-rt-transports-http-3.1.12.jar!/org/apache/cxf/transport/http/policy/HTTPClientAssertionBuilder$HTTPClientPolicyAssertion.class, jar:file:///private/var/folders/rw/9_fr4s6s01d5vcykl3fqkd7d3j59v0/T/jetty-0.0.0.0-0-attache-api-rest.war-_api-any-13258162480745251787.dir/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/cxf-rt-transports-http-3.1.4.jar!/org/apache/cxf/transport/http/policy/HTTPClientAssertionBuilder$HTTPClientPolicyAssertion.class
```

I can understand that this is occurring because 2 jars have same class and I have to exclude some dependencies but I am not getting how to exclude and what should be the criteria.

Comment: Have you tried using a maven exclusion?

Comment: Actually I tried, but not getting which particular dependency to exclude, what should be the criteria ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's take one of your conflicts as an example:

> org.apache.cxf.transport.http.policy.HTTPClientAssertionBuilder$HTTPClientPolicyAssertion
>   scanned from multiple locations:
>
> jar:file:///private/var/folders/rw/9_fr4s6s01d5vcykl3fqkd7d3j59v0/T/jetty-0.0.0.0-0-attache-api-rest.war-_api-any-13258162480745251787.dir/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/**cxf-rt-transports-http-3.1.12.jar**!/org/apache/cxf/transport/http/policy/HTTPClientAssertionBuilder$HTTPClientPolicyAssertion.class,
>
> jar:file:///private/var/folders/rw/9_fr4s6s01d5vcykl3fqkd7d3j59v0/T/jetty-0.0.0.0-0-attache-api-rest.war-_api-any-13258162480745251787.dir/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/**cxf-rt-transports-http-3.1.4.jar**!/org/apache/cxf/transport/http/policy/HTTPClientAssertionBuilder$HTTPClientPolicyAssertion.class

Digging deeper (bolded) you can see that the class in question is provided by different version of "cxf-rt-transports-http", namely separate jars for versions 3.1.4 and 3.1.12.

You will need to examine each conflict individually and remove the less desirable jar from the classpath.

The best way to do so is by creating an exclusion, such as:

```
<exclusions>
    <exclusion>  <!-- declare the exclusion here -->
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
</exclusions>
```

You declare this on the dependency that depends on the above.

Which isn't always easy to figure out unless you have software that illustrates the dependency graph.
In Eclipse for example, the Maven POM editor can show you dependencies, conflicts, and generate exclusions for you.

**Selection criteria:**

In most cases you'll probably want the newest version available, so in this case that's likely going to be 3.1.12.
However, you may not want the latest, latest, but a particular stable version that you have extensively tested, yet which doesn't contain any vulnerabilities. So the answer to that isn't straight forward.

If you need a specific version, it may be best to declare an explicit dependency on that artifact in your own pom and exclude it from all others.

**Edit:**

Another reason why you might need to choose a particular version over another is that you may be using another library that in turn relies on a specific version of a conflicting dependency, but has issues with a newer one.

In most cases version numbering is `<major>.<minor>.<bugfix>` and in almost all cases bugfix releases are binary compatible with each other, so in the case of cxf-rt-transports-http above you should be fine selecting 3.1.12.

On the other hand, say you had dependencies A depending on C v1.5.0 and B depending on C v2.1.2. This would be more difficult due to possible incompatibility between those major versions. There may be a feature you need in v2, but A is not compatible as an important method that A relies on was removed.

You would then want to check whether a newer version of A exists that will work with C v2.1.X and replace that instead. If there isn't you might either need to downgrade B, or install them side by side. In an extreme case that may involve repackaging the product.
An alternative is to contribute to or fork project A to create a version with updated dependencies.

Maybe it helps to think about the purpose of the warnings:
They're really saying that your code may run, but it is possible that a dependency version is selected in a non-deterministic fashion and that as a result some operations of your code might not to what you expect.
What you want to do is make it deterministic by providing the JVM only one option to choose from in each case. You do that by making a conscious choice as a developer as to which version to use or depend on.

If you have no other reasons, then I'd go for the latest/highest stable version, as that will probably include the most features and bugfixes.
Test thoroughly, as you would, and on the off-chance that you have problems that are not caused by your own code, isolate and report a possible bug, downgrade if you need to until the bug is fixed, and/or contribute a fix yourself.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, can you please tell me deeply about the criteria on which I should select versions.

Comment: The warnings are just warnings - code will run, but if the wrong version is selected, your code may not behave is expected. Removing the duplication by any means resolves that problem,but usually you'd go for the highest version to include the most bugfixes. Other than selecting for highest feature or highest stability, I'm not sure what other information I can provide. Is there anything in particular that causes you doubts as to what to do?

Comment: @Nishthagarg I've added a few more lines, hope they help you.

Comment: Thanks for such clarification, let me try digging out with help of all these methods you mentioned me. Hope these things work ! Thanks again :)